# How to override view.xml file in custom module

Tags: magento2.3, php-7.2

I have change magnifier vars in view.xml file under luma theme. Its working fine .

I have change it in my custom module like this ...

**app/code/XXX/YYY/etc/view.xml.**

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">

        <var name="magnifier">
            <var name="fullscreenzoom">20</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
            <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
            <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
            <var name="width">400</var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
            <var name="height">400</var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
            <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
            <var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
            <var name="mode">outside</var> <!-- Zoom type (outside/inside) -->
        </var>
```

Its not working .

And also
In theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
     <title>theme name</title>
     <parent>Magento/blank
```

**registration.php:**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/OX/yyy',
    __DIR__
);
```

**/app/design/frontend/XXX/yyy/etc/view.xml**

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
        <var name="magnifier">
            <var name="fullscreenzoom">20</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
            <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
            <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
            <var name="width">400</var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
            <var name="height">400</var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
            <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
            <var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
            <var name="mode">outside</var> <!-- Zoom type (outside/inside) -->
        </var>
  </view>
```

its also not working.

If anything i want to change it.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

To create a theme and override a view.xml

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme-name}/registration.php

```
<?php                
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'frontend/{Vendor}/{theme-name}',
__DIR__);
```

then create theme.xml

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme-name}/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>Theme Title</title>
<parent>Magento/blank</parent></theme>
```

Check whether the theme is installed by the following query via mysql

```
select * from theme;
```

then add

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme-name}/etc/view.xml

and add composer.json in

> app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme-name}/composer.json

then add the below code in it

```
{
"name": "{vendor}/{theme-name}",
"description": "N/A",
"require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.0.*",
    "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
},
"type": "magento2-theme",
"version": "100.0.1",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ]
}}
```

You must configure your theme to see the changes on frontend.

To configure new theme for your store, just follow the below steps :

> Go to-> content-> configuration-> select your store-> then change the new theme by clicking drop down and save configuration.

NOTE : After creating theme setup:upgrade and once after configured theme cache:flush.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have done all step as you mentioned above ..except  Go to-> content-> configuration-> select your store-> then change the new theme by clicking drop down and save configuration.

Comment: Bcoz, the design configuration grid was empty.

Comment: Is it working or not?

Comment: theme was created in table ...i can't config store  ..Go to-> content-> configuration-> select your store-> then change the new theme by clicking drop down and save configuration.

Comment: @prathap.updated on my post

Comment: Add composer.json into the theme. updated answer

Comment: still not working

Comment: php bin/magento set:up and php bin/magento set:stat-cont:dep -f 
run these commands

Answer (score 2):

according documentation custom theme files must be under following path:

`/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>`

So your view.xml should be there:

`/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/etc`

Comment: updated my post

Comment: did you follow all the theme creation guideline? https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html