# Magento 2.3 How to overrride paid theme template?

Tags: magento2.3.0, custom-theme, template-override

I am working in magento 2.3.0 with paid theme. I want to override paid theme templates without changing theme files. So that in future if theme updates my functionality still remains. 
How can I do this ?

Comment: What do you want to override in theme files?

Comment: I want to render sub categories with images as grid on category pages. So want to override Magento_Catalog/templates/category/products.phtml

Comment: Create a new theme with your paid theme as parent theme

Comment: How to create a new child theme ?

Comment: Just follow this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264247/how-to-override-view-xml-file-in-custom-module/264263#264263

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create child theme of that paid theme(parent theme) and then customise it as per requirement. You can refer following link for the same.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/264263/6084

Answer (score 0):

**I want to render sub categories with images as grid on category pages. So want to override Magento_Catalog/templates/category/products.phtml" -chanchal**

For this you don't need to override the theme template file, this job is done using the extension.

For this follow steps below:

1. Open link "https://github.com/pratikmage/magento2-subcategory/" and download the file, extract in your "app/code" folder.
2. Do necessary changes related to vendor name, path etc.
3. To install this module run upgrade & deploy commands.
4. Create Static Block and assign 
   {{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="subcat" template="category/sub.phtml"}}
5. Edit category from admin panel and select cms block in category content.
   For this refer below link: 
   https://belvg.com/blog/adding-a-static-block-to-a-category-page-in-magento-2-0.html
6. Clear the cache and check it.